# В редакторе кода qt-creator + cmake сыпет ошибками при использовании std::get и std::variant если в коде есть хоть один вызов std::visit

Tags: c++, qtcreator, c++17

Пишу код в qt-creator 4.8.0 + cmake (на linux). При использовании функций std::get и std::variant, если в этой же единице трансляции вызывается std::visit, IDE выдаёт множество ошибок.

```
class Foo {
   public:
    int a{1};
    int b{2};
    void set_a(const int new_a) { a = new_a; }
};

class Bat {
    int Arr[200]{};
};

int main() {
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    std::variant<Foo, Bat> var_1;
    if (a == 0)
        var_1 = Foo();
    else
        var_1 = Bat();
    std::variant<Foo, Bat> var_2;
    std::visit(
        [](auto& arg) {
        },
        var_2);

    std::get<Foo>(var_1).a = 444;
    std::get<Foo>(var_1).set_a(124);        // IDE выдаёт ошибку (this argument to member function 'set_a' fas type 'const Foo', but function is not marked const)
    cout << std::get<Foo>(var_1).a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

При этом код компилируется (GCC 7.3). У меня есть участок кода, где активно используется std::get, и после добавления туда вызов std::visit, qt-creator окрасил в красный 2к строк кода. Что можно с этим сделать?

#### UPD 2: В CMake скрипт внесены правки предложенные KoVadim:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(fast_test_2)
add_definitions(-DBUILD_TYPE_="${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}")
add_definitions(-DPROJECT_NAME_="${PROJECT_NAME}")

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS                 "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17 -Wall -pthread ") #
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG           "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17 -Wall -pthread -g -DDREAL_DEBUG -DDREAL_TRACE -fno-inline")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL      "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17 -Wall -pthread -Os -DNDEBUG")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE         "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17 -Wall -pthread -O3 -DNDEBUG")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17 -Wall -pthread -O2 -g")

set (Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set (Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED OFF)
set (Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS ON)
set (BOOST_ROOT "/home/fieldy/LinaroToolchain/target_lib/boost_1_67_0/")
find_package(Boost REQUIRED system)
include_directories (SYSTEM ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

#### UPD 3:

Вчера создал [пост](https://forum.qt.io/topic/97947/qt-creator-cmake-and-c-17-code-model/2) на официальном форуме Qt, там сказали, что скорее всего это ошибка в текущей code model.

#### UPD 4:

Попробовал воспроизвести тоже самое в CLion. Создал проект, вставил код и никаких сообщений об ошибках не было. Но потом я попробовал подключить внешний toolchain. Зашёл Settings->Build->Toolchains, там создал новый toolchain и выбрал в качестве компиляторов и отладчика внешний тулчейн GCC 7.3 который я собирал для кросскомпиляции под ARM. После этого CLion стал показывать мне те же самые ошибки в тех же местах. Подчеркну, что в qt-creator использовался системный тулчейн который сейчас лежит в дебиановских репозиториях.

Comment: Оно просто окрасило красным или реально не компилируется?

Comment: @KoVadim Просто говорит что не скомпилирует, но cmake отлично собирает проект. Я написал об этом в вопросе.

Comment: Дело в том, что подсветкой ошибок налету заниматься clang, который по умолчанию использует 11 или 14 стандарт. А visit это уже 17. Ищите настройки clang

Comment: @mrFieldy Вы писали, что используете cmake - не могли бы вы привести код вашего CMakeLists.txt?

Answer (score 6):

Проверкой синтаксиса "на лету" занимается clang через встроенный плагин. А он иногда ошибается и неверно определяет версию стандарта. А иногда он спотыкается на странных кусках кода (особенно, где то в недрах windows.h).

Можно помочь ему и подсказать версию. Tools->Options->C++->CodeModel, кнопка Manage. Там скопируйте существующий подходящий профиль и добавьте опцию `-std=c++17`. Возможно, нужно будет сделать ревизию и выбрать более подходящие Вам.

Нашел на [LOR](https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/development/14428488) похожий вопрос. Похоже, там это активно отпиливают и сильно почему то не хотят (хотя я и догадываюсь почему). Также там есть парочка новых рецептов.

Также неплохо добавить в cmake команду `set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)` - она заставляет cmake вставить команды, который сгенерируют специальный json файл, с списком опций компиляций. И тогда clang может его увидеть и будет знать все нужные опции.

**UPD**

Я кажется разгадал причину. Версия cmake указана как 3.7. Если пойти на страницу cmake и посмотреть по поводу [CXX_STANDARD](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html#prop_tgt:CXX_STANDARD), то видно, что 17 там ещё не поддерживается. А в [3.8](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html#prop_tgt:CXX_STANDARD) уже да. Это объясняет тот странный факт, что версия компилятора явно указанна в `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS*`, что меня изначально немного озадачило.

То есть, компилятору насильно версию протолкнули, но cmake о ней не знает. И другие участники также.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Clang говорит, что не может распознать этот флаг (Option "std=c++17 is invalid."). Пробовал флаги  "std=c++14" и "std=c++1z" и прочие, что пришли в голову, не берёт. Если вбить эти настройки насильно, то при перезапуске qt creator clang просто падает.

Comment: у меня также ругалось, но работало. А вот падений я не видел. минус перед опцией точно не забыли?

Comment: '-w -std=c++14' - вот скопированная строка с опциями. При запуске qtcreator без остановки сыпятся ошибки:   2018-12-24T17:19:39 Clang Code Model: Error: The clangbackend process has finished unexpectedly and was restarted.
2018-12-24T17:19:39 Clang Code Model: Error: The clangbackend process has finished unexpectedly and was restarted.
2018-12-24T17:19:39 Clang Code Model: Error: The clangbackend process has finished unexpectedly and was restarted.

Comment: Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38053992/enable-c14-in-qtcreators-clangcodemodel)  cmannett85 говорит что после версии 4.5 qt-creator вообще выкидывает эти  флаги (а не только кидает варнинги). Там говорят что всё заработает если задать соответствующую опцию в Cmake, но у меня эта опция стоит.

Comment: да, вижу. Видимо прогресс не стоит на месте... Очень жаль...

Comment: В общем пока что ничего не помогло. Я привязал флаги компиляции напрямую к компилятору 'Platform Codegen Flags: -std=c++17' как советовали по вашей ссылке. Это тоже не возымело действия.

Comment: Я кажется разгадал Вашу проблему, читайте обновление ответа

Comment: Обновил CMake скрипт в вопросе. Обновление Cmake не помогло. Я сейчас еще [заметил](https://yadi.sk/i/e9nQeooVgpAYYg), что IDE выдаёт мне предупреждение связанное с code model.

Comment: Вы не все мои правки внесли. Зачем оставлять версию стандарта в опциях компилятора. Он и сам их прекрасно должен подставить. Если нет - ищите ошибку.

Comment: Я сократил скрипт до трёх строк: `set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
    add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")`